# How to recharge sim card programmatically in android

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I want to make an app that accepts voucher of some network operator and recharge the sim card, I tried to use Telephony Manager but i couldn't find such thing to help me make the call within the app not via an intent to another calling app.

Answer (score 1):

Account recharge is not part of Telephony. It's on carrier side so it all depeneds what voucher really means. Sometimes it's just a sequence of digits you can 'call', so just do that. In other cases it requires sending text message to special number with the code from voucher. Both operations can be done with currently available APIs.

Comment: Its a sequence of digits that i can call, but what i want to do in my app is to make the call in the background and response with the success of recharging, do you think its possible?